# Resolving merge conflicts in pull requests

Tags: git

My usual way of dealing with merge conflicts in pull requests is to check out the target_branch and pull from the repo. Then merge the target_branch into my feature_branch. Now I have the conflicts on my feature_branch ready to be resolved, but I also have every other change pushed to the target_branch as well.

Is there an approach that only fetches the changes causing conflicts, so that I do not rewrite the history on my colleagues commits?

Comment: You could rebase the feature_branch onto the target_branch; this is something you can do as you go along (e.g. at the start of every session) so you don't have to deal with all of the conflicts at the end.

Comment: But wouldn't this method still give me all the changes done to the target_branch? In my instance, the target_branch is develop, so that would mean a lot of changes that are unrelated to my feature.

Comment: The unrelated changes won't cause any conflicts, so that's not a problem. You don't rewrite other people's history, either, only the new commits on your feature_branch.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how does this prevent me from getting unrelated changes polluting my branch? I'm relatively new to git (and a bit daft).

Comment: It's unclear to me what problem you think you're trying to solve. What do you mean *"polluting"*? Why would you *not* have all of the other changes? It's *all* got to be integrated at some point if your changes are ever going to get into the target_branch.

Comment: I don't want all the other changes because they already have been merged into develop through other pull requests. My method today for fixing merge conflicts is to merge develop into my feature_branch, fix the conflicts, and finally push my changes back up to the pull requests. But by doing this, I end up as the author of all the unrelated commits that I merged into the feature_branch from develop when I obtained the conflicts.

So if all my changes pertain to a.py, but a teammate has changed something in b.py I would end up as the author of that commit. That is what I ment by polluting

Comment: Then rebasing does address this because, as above, *you don't rewrite other people's history*. You rewrite your own commits to have a new ancestor, the new tip of target_branch, fixing any conflicts as you try to reapply them to their new parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the way I'd address this is with a [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). Assuming you're starting with something like:

```
target_branch  ...--A---B---C---D---E
                         \
feature_branch            F---G
```

Then the following:

```
git checkout feature_branch
git rebase target_branch
```

Will result in the following:

```
target_branch  ...--A---B---C---D---E
                                     \
feature_branch                        F'--G'
```

This has two useful properties for you:

1. None of the commits on `target_branch` get rewritten, so they retain their original authors; and
2. The rewriting of first `F` (becoming `F'`, with a new parent `E` instead of `B`) then `G` (becoming `G'`, with a new parent `F'` instead of `F`) allows you to resolve any conflicts with `C`, `D` and `E` stepwise.

The result is a pair of commits on `feature_branch` that can easily be applied back to `target_branch` without conflicts.

**Note** that if you've already pushed `feature_branch` to the remote, the rewriting of history means that you'll have to force `push` (ideally `--force-with-lease`) these new commits.